# Corona AdMob Integration, why no AdListener event?

Tags: lua, admob, coronasdk

I posted this in the corona forums but no response.  There must be something obvious I'm missing, hope someone can help!

I'm starting out integrating admobs and can't seem to get an adlistener event.

I've got this code:

main.lua:

```
appID = "ca-app-pub-8278249997676996/7462506469"
ads = require("ads")
-- Create a text object to display ad status
statusText = display.newText( "ad status text", 0, 0, native.systemFontBold, 22 )
statusText:setTextColor( 255 )
statusText:setReferencePoint( display.CenterReferencePoint )
statusText.x, statusText.y = display.contentWidth * 0.5, 160

-- Set up ad listener.
function adListener( event )
    statusText.text = "got an ad listener event!"
-- event table includes:
--                 event.provider
--                event.isError (e.g. true/false )

local msg = event.response

-- just a quick debug message to check what response we got from the library
print("Message received from the ads library: ", msg)

if event.isError then
    statusText:setTextColor( 255, 0, 0 )
    statusText.text = "Error Loading Ad " .. msg
    statusText.x = display.contentWidth * 0.5

    --showAd( "banner" )
else
    statusText:setTextColor( 0, 255, 0 )
    statusText.text = "Successfully Loaded Ad : " .. msg
    statusText.x = display.contentWidth * 0.5
end
end

 -- Initialize the 'ads' library with the provider you wish to use.
if appID then
    print("initialising admob")
    ads.init( "admob", appID, adListener )
end
```

and

anotherfile.lua

```
statusText.text = "Let's show an ad please"
ads.show( "banner", {x=0, y=0} )
```

The statusText.text changes to "let's show an ad pleas"e, and ads.show( is the next line of code.  But there is no further change to statusText.text, which means the adListener is not being called.  There's also no ad being shown.

In my build settings I have:

```
androidPermissions = 
{
"android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE",
"android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE",
"android.permission.VIBRATE",
"android.permission.INTERNET"
},


plugins = 
{
-- key is the name passed to Lua's 'require()'
["CoronaProvider.ads.admob"] =
{
      -- required
    publisherId = "com.sportspunter",
},
},
```

Any suggestions welcome please!

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You changed the publisher ID in the plugin settings in your build.settings file.  Try this:

```
publisherId = "com.coronalabs",
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have coded everything correctly, but I'm not 100% I know the correct answer. The only thing I can think of is you need to `redeclare` the code in `main.lua` in `anotherfile.lua`. Probably the variables aren't correctly declared so they aren't getting transferred.

Also I'm pretty sure ad's don't display on the simulator, so make sure you build for the device.

Your `build.settings` looks fine.

Hope this helps.